# Inserting multiple data in to a Treeview in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

```
RecreateBody()
InvoicesScreen=ttk.Frame(bodyframe)
InvoicesScreen.grid(column=0, row=0)
InvoicesScreenTitle=ttk.Label(titleframe,text="Invoices Screen")
InvoicesScreenTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
tree.destroy()
tree = ttk.Treeview(InvoicesScreen)
tree.grid(column=0, row=0)
tree['columns']=('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
tree.column("#0", width=0)
tree.column("one", width=50 )
tree.column("two", width=200)
tree.column("three", width=100)
tree.column("four", width=100)
tree.heading("one", text="id")
tree.heading("two", text="date")
tree.heading("three", text="total")
tree.heading("four", text="no of items")
c.execute('SELECT id FROM invoice')
invoiceid = c.fetchall()
```

I have tried every version of `tree.insert` and have been unable to to successfully pull data in to my `Treeview` from my database.

I know the invoice `id` is fetching the right data because I tested it with the print command. Getting data in to the database from entry boxes was easy enough but have been stuck for an age trying to display the data within my program.

Never used `Treeview` before in my life and the docs for `tree.insert` left me extremely confused.

Comment: please show what you've tried. How are you inserting data into the widget? The `insert` method is fairly well documented.

Comment: Between http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html and http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html you should be able to write something that works.  If not, show the failing code.

Comment: No point reinventing the wheel.  I always search for "ttk treeview multilist box" when wanting to find it again.  You can just substitute your heads and list of data into a program that already works.

Comment: Through trial and error i came up with this: tree.insert('', 1, values=invoiceid) However i need the values to be placed only in the left column and not across the row